How to use custom font in react native when using @callstack/repack?
I already know how to use custom font in react native when using metro.

download the font into the project.
configure the react-native.config.js file.
execute npx react-native-asset

But how can I use custom font in @callstack/repack? I know the @callstack/repack/assets-loader and this is my configuration:
export default (config, {platform, devServer}) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: Repack.getAssetExtensionsRegExp(
      Repack.ASSET_EXTENSIONS.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg')
    ),
    use: {
      loader: '@callstack/repack/assets-loader',
      options: {
        platform,
        devServerEnabled: Boolean(devServer),
        scalableAssetExtensions: Repack.SCALABLE_ASSETS,
      },
    },
  })
  config.plugins.push(new Repack.plugins.AssetsResolverPlugin({platform}))
  return config
}

